# Python loops too slow for numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an image as a matrix (`ndarray`) of shape (720, 1280, 3) with RGB pixels (variable: `original`) and another `ndarray` of shape (720, 1280) which is made of booleans (variable: `im`).

for every `True` value in `im` I want `original`'s corresponding pixel to be of color [0, 0, 255].

I tried (with both arrays flattened)

```
for i in range(im.size):
  if(im[i] == True):
    original[i] = [0, 0, 255]
```

but its too slow to have it as a video output.

Any ideas how I can speed this up?

Comment: From array's perspective, code (1D) and comments (2D) don't match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same as doing (without flattening your arrays):

```
original[im == True] = [0, 0, 255]
```

That is the vectorized representation of your for loop.

Comment: Or just `original[im] = [0,0,255]`.